# SQL LAG() function with condition where

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have my table like this:

```
    WITH 
my_table (user_id, date, event_name, value) AS (
    values 
    (1,'2021-10-01', 'level', 5),
    (1,'2021-10-03', 'purchase', null),
    (1,'2021-10-05', 'purchase', null),
    (2,'2021-10-02', 'level', 10),
    (2,'2021-10-03', 'purchase', null)
) 
SELECT *
FROM my_table
```

| user_id | date | event_name | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | level | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 | purchase |  |
| 1 | 2021-10-05 | purchase |  |
| 2 | 2021-10-02 | level | 10 |
| 2 | 2021-10-03 | purchase |  |

All I want is to add column with the last `level` achieved before every purchase for every `user_id`.
Desired table should look like this

| user_id | date | event_name | level | level_achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | level | 5 |  |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 | purchase |  | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-10-05 | purchase |  | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-10-02 | level | 10 |  |
| 2 | 2021-10-03 | purchase |  | 10 |

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What happens if there is a record for user_id 1 on 2021-10-04 that has a level of 3? Would the level_achieved for the purchase records for user 1 both be 5, or would one be 3 and one be 5?

Comment: You could try the window function LAST_VALUE() and if you partition that by user_id and order that by Date, you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: @dfundako it should be one with 3 and another one with 5

Comment: @josh No, it's not working, because some purchases can happen twice in one level.

Comment: I think you have to specify IGNORE NULLS ... but I like Mustafa's answer better with the subquery

Comment: you could use lag function: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that level can't go down you can use just `max` which will ignore `null`'s:

```sql
SELECT *,
    if(value is null, max(value) over(partition by user_id order by date)) level_achieved
FROM my_table;
```

Output:

| user_id | date | event_name | value | level_achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | level | 5 | NULL |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 | purchase | NULL | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-10-05 | purchase | NULL | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-10-02 | level | 10 | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-10-03 | purchase | NULL | 10 |

Or using `last_value` with `ignore nulls` option:

```sql
SELECT *,
    if(value is null, last_value(value) IGNORE NULLS over(partition by user_id order by date)) level_achieved
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to create a subquery with the following:

```
user_id, level, date as date_start, lead(date) over(partition by user_id order by date asc) as date_end
(where level is not null)
```

You will get a structure like:

```
user_id, level, date_start, date_end
```

Next you can join with:

```
        my_table ON my_table.date >= sub_query.date_start 
    AND my_table.date < sub_query.date_end
AND my_table.user_id = sub_query.user_id
```

With this you can easily get the level for that specific date range.

Good luck